# Django taking another users stuff

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am adding sales order to my project and only authenticated users can create sales order with their stuffs like contacts customer, items etc but in the UI it is showing me another users options as well. For example I am going to create sales order and I have 1 customer contact and 1 item. in templates instead of showing 1 customer contact and 1 item, it is showing a number of stuffs of another users too.

**models.py** here it is

```
class SalesOrder(TimeModel):

   customer = models.ForeignKey(ClientContact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   so_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
   so_items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   author = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
     unique_together = ('so_items', 'author')
```

I have added unique_together but it does not help. for views i am using CBV

**views.py**

```
class Sales(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  model = SalesOrder
  template_name = 'sales/sales_order.html'
  fields = ['customer', 'so_date', 'so_items',]

  def get_queryset(self):
    return super(Sales, self).get_queryset().filter(author=self.request.user)

  def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)

  def test_func(self):
    so_order = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == so_order.author:
        return True
    return False
```

how can i solve this issue? any help?

Comment: Can you post your forms.py, please? I believe you'll need to filter the items you're displaying by the `request.user`

Comment: No i cant because i did not add forms.py i did it with model fields

Comment: You then need to override your `get_queryset` method and filter the items by the `self.request.user` logged.

Comment: def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Sales, self).get_queryset().filter(author=self.request.user)  i have added this but it did not help

Comment: Please update your code here with what you've changed.

Comment: write queryset in form_valid() and render template in form_valid(). inside form_valid your have access on self.request. what's your problem ?

Comment: here please look through

Comment: with get_queryset() does not work ?

Comment: @gachdavit yes does not work

Comment: Why ?  Your model is not filtered ? You have additional rows ?

Comment: it is filtered yes i have but they are not related to those i have shown

Comment: You are trying to filter based on author (FK), which belongs to CustomUser. What does CustomUser represents ? self.request.user (Returns User instance. Which is django's builtin Model/Table), but you have your own CustomUser. Maybe they have different ids.

Comment: customuser is user authentication when they are registered they will have own items  client contacts they can make sales orders

Comment: self.request.user equals to author how can they have different ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is solved by adding `get_context_data()` in the view

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(Sales, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['form'].fields['customer'].queryset = ClientContact.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
       context['form'].fields['so_items'].queryset = Item.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
       return context
```